# Why was the Weasley family clock featured in Harry Potter of the Chamber of Secrets?

Tags: harry-potter

Why was the Weasley family clock with an arm for each family member, showing their current whereabouts, featured in the second film when it is mentioned for the first time in the fourth Harry Potter book?

Answer (score 6):

### The screenwriter took inspiration from the other novels

On the chamber of DVD there is an [interview](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2003/0302-newsround-mzimba.htm) featuring the screenwriter Steve Kloves and J.K. Rowling:

> Lizo: ... Can you explain both how you worked together to produce the final script because it must be very very different writing a book as compared to writing a film.
>
> Steve: Yeah, you know, I mean, I just... steal her best stuff, for the most part...
>
> JKR: [Nodding] That's basically it. And I don't sue!

So that's likely where he took inspiration from, the fourth book, and he most likely considers that clock worth including.

Bear in mind, that the fourth book was published 2 years before the film was released, so it's not even as though he'd have needed an unpublished version to "steal" ideas from.